# What is the best way to get a value in three encapsulated Maps with Groovy/Java

Tags: java, groovy, hashmap

What is the best way to get a value in three encapsulated Maps with Groovy/Java

Here an example :

```
locations {

    apache {

        RewriteRule {
            source = '^/apache(.*)$'
            dest = 'http://192.x.x.x:8000/apache$1'
        }
    }

    tomcat {

        RewriteRule {
            source = '^/tomcat/(.*)$'
            dest = 'http://192.x.x.x:8000/tomcat/media/$1'
        }
    }


}
```

I would like to find a specific value of `locations.x.RewriteRule.source`

Here my solution :
But I'm looking for something more easy and efficent

```
public boolean isSourceMatchURI(String uri) {
    boolean result = false
    locations.each {
        location, rules ->
            (rules as Map).each { rewriteRule, values ->
                java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = (uri =~ (values as Map).source)
                if (matcher.matches())
                    result = matcher.matches()
                println((values as Map).source)
            }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: You realize that those aren't Maps, right?  That looks like Config.  You also might perhaps want to state what you want the output to be?  Are you just detecting that a specific value exists, or what?

Comment: I want to match a string with the source attribute. So for every URL I try to look for the first source(regex) that matchs with it.

Comment: Here My solution but I would like to get something more easier : 
    

`public boolean isSourceMatchURI(String uri) {
        boolean result = false
        locations.each {
            location, rules ->
                (rules as Map).each { rewriteRule, values ->
                    java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = (uri =~ (values as Map).source)
                    if (matcher.matches())
                        result = matcher.matches()
                    println((values as Map).source)
                }
        }
        return result
    }`

Comment: Easiest change I see would be to use "find" rather than "each", as find stops once you've found a match, and returns the item that had the match.

Comment: Thank you and I changed the solution using for loop and break